# How can I recover deleted contact form from CMS in contact form 7 Version 5.0.5 (locally) in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

How can I recover deleted contact form from CMS in contact form 7 Version 5.0.5 (locally) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't is the short answer.  CF7 plugin does use the WordPress core post management functionality and simply deletes form posts.

However, if you use a plugin extension such as the [Smart Grid](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/), it re-introduces the WordPress post management functionality for the CF7 forms custom post type wpcf7_contact_form, and therefore when you delete a form (post) it gets pushed into the Trash bin from which you can either permanently delete it or recover it.